# Upgrade MariaDB 5.5.64 to MariaDB 10 Is it necessary?

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress health status says

> The SQL server is a required piece of software for the database WordPress uses to store all your site’s content and settings.
>
> For optimal performance and security reasons, we recommend running MariaDB version 10.0 or higher. Contact your web hosting company to correct this.

[image: Screenshot]

Is it necessary? Because my site is just a tube site (like a movie wordpress) and is this gonna benefit my site interms of speed etc?

Comment: For optimal performance and security reasons: Do you want to avoid your site being hacked? List of vulnerabilities fixed in various versions: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/security/ and history of vulnerabilities here https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=12010&product_id=&version_id=&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=1&trc=74&sha=6dab5368b66701e00ee923ef54238c8dd25e7dfa

Comment: "A lot of people think their sites are safe from attacks because they don’t contain valuable and sensitive business information. However, there are plenty of other reasons why sites get hacked, such as:

    to spread malware,
    adding bandwidth to bot networks, which are often used for Denial of Service (DDoS) attacks,
    black-hat Search Engine Optimization (SEO),
    activism / hacktivism,
    just for practice and fun
"
From https://securityboulevard.com/2019/10/top-reasons-why-wordpress-websites-get-hacked-and-how-you-can-stop-it/   Scroll down to how - #4: outdated software

Comment: I have no knowledge about the DB parts, I just do the basic stuff on Wordpress, create a new content and post. My site is still small and few traffic that's why I'm wondering if upgrading version will benefit my site in terms of speed since it mentions optimal performance.

Comment: Well it has already said that "For optimal performance".   It is usually a good idea to stay fairly up to date, a good host normally helps with this.  Mine will run versions in parallel for while allowing you to choose when you upgrade.  It does eventually drop the oldest.  Also bear in mind in mind that the greater the gap in versions, the more likely there may be oddities when upgrading.       Talk to your host, sometimes it is as easy as ticking a box and then retesting your site to make sure all ok.  Usually is ok if using wp.

Comment: Okay sir, I will ask my host regarding with this. Thank you so much for answering my question. I really appreciate it.